# Problem with uploading files to Spring Boot app using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot

I'm struggling with uploading files to my Spring Boot app using AJAX. I read many tutorials, watched many videos and somehow, it still doesn't work for me. I have a class `Account` and i want to upload avatar to this. Here is my code:
JS:

```
inputAvatar.on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var file = inputAvatar.prop('files')[0]
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file)

    $.ajax({
        url: "/user/my-account/upload-avatar-image",
        type: "post",
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(status => {
        console.log(status);
    });
});
```

Java:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/my-account/upload-avatar-image")
    public int uploadAvatarImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile imageFile){
        return accountService.uploadAvatarImage(imageFile);
    }
```

```
    public int uploadAvatarImage(MultipartFile imageFile){
        String folder = this.getClass().getResource("/images/avatars").getPath();
        try {
            byte[] bytes = imageFile.getBytes();
            Path path = Paths.get(folder + imageFile.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(imageFile);
        return 0;
    }
```

When i upload file i get a Java warning:

> 2020-09-08 02:36:58.232  WARN 14140 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
> Required request part 'imageFile' is not present]

and in the console of my browser:

> jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 POST
> http://localhost:8080/user/my-account/upload-avatar-image 400

and for now i don't know on which side there is a wrong piece of code.
Can anyone explain to me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm kinda dumb, it was pretty easy. `@RequestParam` has to match what I put into `formData.append("file", file)`. So in this case I need to add a value of what i append to `formData` to `@RequestParam`:
`@RequestParam("file")`